# Added another developer account to my computer and the old one no longer works

Tags: ios

I just added a 2nd developer account to my computer to distribute apps.  I wanted to keep everything seperated so I created another account for it.

I can validate and send apps with the new account, but now I get an error when I validate apps under the old account.

the error says my bundle contains a key value that is not allowed, the complete error message is

"Invalid code signing entitlments the entilment in your app bundle signature does not match the one conained in the provision profile. the budle key keu value that is not allowed 73pngm574.abctest

I'm using the xcode wildcard id for my app so abctest is the bundle id and 73pngm574 is my dveloper id

Comment: I have 4 different accounts on my computer and Xcode 5.1.1 handles them properly, the _Code Sign Identity_ should match to _Provisioning Profile_. you cannot mix them, otherwise you will receive the error what you have received.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that has worked for me is using Xcode to set things up correctly for you. Xcode --> Preferences --> Accounts. Use the account setup to link to your developer account and Xcode should sync things up for you.

You may need to remove any old keys or profiles you've copied in or tried setting up previously. Not exactly ideal, but "usually" works for me.